# Changing star symbol with letters in Package authblk

Tags: symbols, titles, authblk

I am using package authblk in an article class. I need to change the *,a with a,* after the first Author Name. How can I do that? Please see the code below and the attached figure. I put a rectangle in red around the parts that need to be changed in the figure. I posted this question also in latex-community [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=24004). Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title {\bf  Title}
 \author[,a]{Author Name\thanks{Corresponding author. Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\\\hspace*{1.8em} E-mail: email@123.com}}

\author[b]{Author Name}
\affil[a]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\affil[b]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}


\date{\today}
\begin {document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a really elegant solution, but for a one shot it seems not really unmanageable.

The problem is that the optional argument to `\author` is added as a footnote marker after the author name, which already has `\thanks`, is absorbed and typeset. Doing it differently would require very deep surgery on `authblk` macros.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% patch author so that `\empty` is non empty ;-)
\xpatchcmd{\author}{\relax#1\relax}{\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax}{}{}

\title{Title}
\author[\empty]{%
  Author Name\textsuperscript{a,}\thanks{Corresponding author.
    Tel.: +0 (000) 000 0000 ext. 00000; fax: +0 (000) 000 0000.\\
    \hspace*{1.8em} E-mail: email@123.com}}

\author[b]{Author Name}
\affil[a]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}
\affil[b]{Department of , University of , Address, BB, CC}


\date{\today}
\begin {document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]